# Visual Studio Setup Project - Create shortcut of exe file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installation

I have made a simple project that allow to Drap & Drop CSV file on to its EXE file to automatically read the data and export to Excel file.
When I test the program by Drap & Drop CSV file to the EXE file in bin/Debug and Release folder, or to the shortcut of the EXE file I place on Desktop, everything is fine.

When I make a Deployment project for the above project, and follow all the steps to make shortcut of the program, I cannot do the Drap & Drop on the shortcut after install the program.
The reason seem to be that the target of the shortcut is not the EXE file, but (as indicate in the Properties View in VS) [Primary output].

I have tried to manually create a shortcut of the EXE file in the installation folder, and it worked fine.

Could anyone help me on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u creating window setup project ... then it displayed icon is `Advertisement` not a Shortcut link..
and you create a shortcut of your Exe then ...its a creating a shortcut link ...

These shortcuts are called Advertised shortcuts. They will give the application abilities of installation-on-demand and advertisement. When a user click on such a shortcut, Windows Installer will check the integrity of the application and automatically install/repair missing or corrupted components.

**To disable the advertised shortcuts, you must set a property called DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS to value 1 in the MSI package.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368297(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I have no knowledge about DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS until now. After searching around the net, I have found the Orca tool from Microsoft that allow add this item into MSI file, and solve the problem.